# Formula for Tracking WIN-LOSS record by Sport

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically, I have a spreadsheet that has a column that defines the type of sport being played (football,tennis,soccer, etc...) and a column next to it that either says WIN or LOSS.

In a different cell, I want to be able to keep a WIN-LOSS record that is numberic (1-0,2-1,3-4,etc..)

However, I want this based upon the SPORT. By this I mean that I want 4 different cells, one that tracks the tennis record, one that tracks the football record, baseball, and hockey.

PS - The sport description is in the range of F3:F100 and the WIN/LOSS is in C3:C100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use formulas for that, e.g. `COUNTIFS` can help you.

`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$22,E2,$B$2:$B$22,"WIN")&" - "&COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$22,E2,$B$2:$B$22,"LOSS")`

[image]